# JSON.parse with special chracters

Tags: javascript, json

I'm sorry for posting this but I after so many hours of pulling my hair I can't seem to make any more progress.

I have a JSON string that is being returned to me as part of a JSON object like:

```
{ "name": "value", "artifact": "THE_JSON_STRING" }
```

I'm pulling the artifact out and using JSON.parse works fine most of the time but I came across an issue when the artifact string contains a /" and JSON.parse breaks. I've gone over many solutions and tried what seems like everything but there has to be something I'm doing wrong.  For simplicity this is my code:

```js
var str = '{ "name" : "This is some value \"escaped\""}';
str = str.replace(/\\"/g, 'x')
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

Any help would be much appreciated

https://fiddle.jshell.net/u428x1k7/2/

**Edit**

I'm very new to Javascript but I'm using React with Redux to make a service call to get my data.  Then I try to use the data via props:

**Raw Data Coming from Service Call:**

```
{
    "id": "8b6df083-8f4f-440a-bc67-4c57bf0969bf",
    "name": "My API ",
    "description": "All APIs are added to this category if one is not specified",
    "icon": "fa-university",
    "services": [
        {
            "id": "16e32cfd-b6e7-4c49-b5ef-ebb5456e6639",
            "artifact": "{ \"swagger\": \"2.0\", \"info\": { \"version\": \"1.0.0\", \"title\": \"Swagger Petstore\", \"license\": { \"name\": \"MIT\" } }, \"host\": \"petstore.swagger.io\", \"basePath\": \"/v1\", \"schemes\": [ \"http\" ], \"consumes\": [ \"application/json\" ], \"produces\": [ \"application/json\" ], \"paths\": { \"/pets\": { \"get\": { \"summary\": \"List all pets\", \"operationId\": \"listPets\", \"tags\": [ \"pets\" ], \"parameters\": [ { \"name\": \"limit\", \"in\": \"query\", \"description\": \"How many items to return at one time (max 100)\", \"required\": false, \"type\": \"integer\", \"format\": \"int32\" } ], \"responses\": { \"200\": { \"description\": \"An paged array of pets\", \"headers\": { \"x-next\": { \"type\": \"string\", \"description\": \"A link to the next page of responses\" } }, \"schema\": { \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Pets\" } }, \"default\": { \"description\": \"unexpected error\", \"schema\": { \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Error\" } } } }, \"post\": { \"summary\": \"Create a pet\", \"operationId\": \"createPets\", \"tags\": [ \"pets\" ], \"responses\": { \"201\": { \"description\": \"Null response\" }, \"default\": { \"description\": \"unexpected error\", \"schema\": { \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Error\" } } } } }, \"/pets/{petId}\": { \"get\": { \"summary\": \"Info for a specific pet\", \"operationId\": \"showPetById\", \"tags\": [ \"pets\" ], \"parameters\": [ { \"name\": \"petId\", \"in\": \"path\", \"required\": true, \"description\": \"The id of the pet to retrieve\", \"type\": \"string\" } ], \"responses\": { \"200\": { \"description\": \"Expected response to a valid request\", \"schema\": { \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Pets\" } }, \"default\": { \"description\": \"unexpected error\", \"schema\": { \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Error\" } } } } } }, \"definitions\": { \"Pet\": { \"required\": [ \"id\", \"name\" ], \"properties\": { \"id\": { \"type\": \"integer\", \"format\": \"int64\" }, \"name\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"tag\": { \"type\": \"string\" } } }, \"Pets\": { \"type\": \"array\", \"items\": { \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Pet\" } }, \"Error\": { \"required\": [ \"code\", \"message\" ], \"properties\": { \"code\": { \"type\": \"integer\", \"format\": \"int32\" }, \"message\": { \"type\": \"string\" } } } } }"
    },
    {
        "id": "b4328bbc-bcb0-4313-b80c-a4394e553dd9",
        "artifact": "{ \"swagger\": \"2.0\", \"info\": { \"title\": \"Uber API\", \"description\": \"Move your app forward with the Uber API\", \"version\": \"1.0.0\" }, \"host\": \"api.uber.com\", \"schemes\": [ \"https\" ], \"basePath\": \"/v1\", \"produces\": [ \"application/json\" ], \"paths\": { \"/products\": { \"get\": { \"summary\": \"Product Types\", \"description\": \"The Products endpoint returns information about the Uber products offered at a given location. The response includes the display name and other details about each product, and lists the products in the proper display order.\", \"parameters\": [ { \"name\": \"latitude\", \"in\": \"query\", \"description\": \"Latitude component of location.\", \"required\": true, \"type\": \"number\", \"format\": \"double\" }, { \"name\": \"longitude\", \"in\": \"query\", \"description\": \"Longitude component of location.\", \"required\": true, \"type\": \"number\", \"format\": \"double\" } ], \"tags\": [ \"Products\" ], \"responses\": { \"200\": { \"description\": \"An array of products\", \"schema\": { \"type\": \"array\", \"items\": { \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Product\" } } }, \"default\": { \"description\": \"Unexpected error\", \"schema\": { \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Error\" } } } } }, \"/estimates/price\": { \"get\": { \"summary\": \"Price Estimates\", \"description\": \"The Price Estimates endpoint returns an estimated price range for each product offered at a given location. The price estimate is provided as a formatted string with the full price range and the localized currency symbol.<br><br>The response also includes low and high estimates, and the [ISO 4217](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) currency code for situations requiring currency conversion. When surge is active for a particular product, its surge_multiplier will be greater than 1, but the price estimate already factors in this multiplier.\", \"parameters\": [ { \"name\": \"start_latitude\", \"in\": \"query\", \"description\": \"Latitude component of start location.\", \"required\": true, \"type\": \"number\", \"format\": \"double\" }, { \"name\": \"start_longitude\", \"in\": \"query\", \"description\": \"Longitude component of start location.\", \"required\": true, \"type\": \"number\", \"format\": \"double\" }, { \"name\": \"end_latitude\", \"in\": \"query\", \"description\": \"Latitude component of end location.\", \"required\": true, \"type\": \"number\", \"format\": \"double\" }, { \"name\": \"end_longitude\", \"in\": \"query\", \"description\": \"Longitude component of end location.\", \"required\": true, \"type\": \"number\", \"format\": \"double\" } ], \"tags\": [ \"Estimates\" ], \"responses\": { \"200\": { \"description\": \"An array of price estimates by product\", \"schema\": { \"type\": \"array\", \"items\": { \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/PriceEstimate\" } } }, \"default\": { \"description\": \"Unexpected error\", \"schema\": { \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Error\" } } } } }, \"/estimates/time\": { \"get\": { \"summary\": \"Time Estimates\", \"description\": \"The Time Estimates endpoint returns ETAs for all products offered at a given location, with the responses expressed as integers in seconds. We recommend that this endpoint be called every minute to provide the most accurate, up-to-date ETAs.\", \"parameters\": [ { \"name\": \"start_latitude\", \"in\": \"query\", \"description\": \"Latitude component of start location.\", \"required\": true, \"type\": \"number\", \"format\": \"double\" }, { \"name\": \"start_longitude\", \"in\": \"query\", \"description\": \"Longitude component of start location.\", \"required\": true, \"type\": \"number\", \"format\": \"double\" }, { \"name\": \"customer_uuid\", \"in\": \"query\", \"type\": \"string\", \"format\": \"uuid\", \"description\": \"Unique customer identifier to be used for experience customization.\" }, { \"name\": \"product_id\", \"in\": \"query\", \"type\": \"string\", \"description\": \"Unique identifier representing a specific product for a given latitude & longitude.\" } ], \"tags\": [ \"Estimates\" ], \"responses\": { \"200\": { \"description\": \"An array of products\", \"schema\": { \"type\": \"array\", \"items\": { \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Product\" } } }, \"default\": { \"description\": \"Unexpected error\", \"schema\": { \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Error\" } } } } }, \"/me\": { \"get\": { \"summary\": \"User Profile\", \"description\": \"The User Profile endpoint returns information about the Uber user that has authorized with the application.\", \"tags\": [ \"User\" ], \"responses\": { \"200\": { \"description\": \"Profile information for a user\", \"schema\": { \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Profile\" } }, \"default\": { \"description\": \"Unexpected error\", \"schema\": { \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Error\" } } } } }, \"/history\": { \"get\": { \"summary\": \"User Activity\", \"description\": \"The User Activity endpoint returns data about a user's lifetime activity with Uber. The response will include pickup locations and times, dropoff locations and times, the distance of past requests, and information about which products were requested.<br><br>The history array in the response will have a maximum length based on the limit parameter. The response value count may exceed limit, therefore subsequent API requests may be necessary.\", \"parameters\": [ { \"name\": \"offset\", \"in\": \"query\", \"type\": \"integer\", \"format\": \"int32\", \"description\": \"Offset the list of returned results by this amount. Default is zero.\" }, { \"name\": \"limit\", \"in\": \"query\", \"type\": \"integer\", \"format\": \"int32\", \"description\": \"Number of items to retrieve. Default is 5, maximum is 100.\" } ], \"tags\": [ \"User\" ], \"responses\": { \"200\": { \"description\": \"History information for the given user\", \"schema\": { \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Activities\" } }, \"default\": { \"description\": \"Unexpected error\", \"schema\": { \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Error\" } } } } } }, \"definitions\": { \"Product\": { \"properties\": { \"product_id\": { \"type\": \"string\", \"description\": \"Unique identifier representing a specific product for a given latitude & longitude. For example, uberX in San Francisco will have a different product_id than uberX in Los Angeles.\" }, \"description\": { \"type\": \"string\", \"description\": \"Description of product.\" }, \"display_name\": { \"type\": \"string\", \"description\": \"Display name of product.\" }, \"capacity\": { \"type\": \"string\", \"description\": \"Capacity of product. For example, 4 people.\" }, \"image\": { \"type\": \"string\", \"description\": \"Image URL representing the product.\" } } }, \"PriceEstimate\": { \"properties\": { \"product_id\": { \"type\": \"string\", \"description\": \"Unique identifier representing a specific product for a given latitude & longitude. For example, uberX in San Francisco will have a different product_id than uberX in Los Angeles\" }, \"currency_code\": { \"type\": \"string\", \"description\": \"[ISO 4217](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) currency code.\" }, \"display_name\": { \"type\": \"string\", \"description\": \"Display name of product.\" }, \"estimate\": { \"type\": \"string\", \"description\": \"Formatted string of estimate in local currency of the start location. Estimate could be a range, a single number (flat rate) or \"Metered\" for TAXI.\" }, \"low_estimate\": { \"type\": \"number\", \"description\": \"Lower bound of the estimated price.\" }, \"high_estimate\": { \"type\": \"number\", \"description\": \"Upper bound of the estimated price.\" }, \"surge_multiplier\": { \"type\": \"number\", \"description\": \"Expected surge multiplier. Surge is active if surge_multiplier is greater than 1. Price estimate already factors in the surge multiplier.\" } } }, \"Profile\": { \"properties\": { \"first_name\": { \"type\": \"string\", \"description\": \"First name of the Uber user.\" }, \"last_name\": { \"type\": \"string\", \"description\": \"Last name of the Uber user.\" }, \"email\": { \"type\": \"string\", \"description\": \"Email address of the Uber user\" }, \"picture\": { \"type\": \"string\", \"description\": \"Image URL of the Uber user.\" }, \"promo_code\": { \"type\": \"string\", \"description\": \"Promo code of the Uber user.\" } } }, \"Activity\": { \"properties\": { \"uuid\": { \"type\": \"string\", \"description\": \"Unique identifier for the activity\" } } }, \"Activities\": { \"properties\": { \"offset\": { \"type\": \"integer\", \"format\": \"int32\", \"description\": \"Position in pagination.\" }, \"limit\": { \"type\": \"integer\", \"format\": \"int32\", \"description\": \"Number of items to retrieve (100 max).\" }, \"count\": { \"type\": \"integer\", \"format\": \"int32\", \"description\": \"Total number of items available.\" }, \"history\": { \"type\": \"array\", \"items\": { \"$ref\": \"#/definitions/Activity\" } } } }, \"Error\": { \"properties\": { \"code\": { \"type\": \"integer\", \"format\": \"int32\" }, \"message\": { \"type\": \"string\" }, \"fields\": { \"type\": \"string\" } } } } }"
    }
]
}
```

**Action:**

```
export const RECEIVE_CATEGORY = 'RECEIVE_CATEGORY';
function receiveCategory(category) {
    return {
        type: RECEIVE_CATEGORY,
        category
    }
}

export function fetchCategory(categoryID) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch(requestCategory(categoryID))

        return fetch(`${baseURL}/categories/${categoryID}`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept' : 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => dispatch(receiveCategory(json)))
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
}
```

**Reducer:**
    function categories(state = [], action) {

```
    switch(action.type) {
            case RECEIVE_CATEGORIES :
            return action.categories;
        case RECEIVE_CATEGORY :

            /* TODO : there has to be an easier way ...*/
            var index = 0;
            for(index; index < state.length; index++) {
                if(action.category.id === state[index].id) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            var array= [...state.slice(0, index),
                action.category,
                ...state.slice(index+1)
            ];
            return array;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just replace the double quotes with single quotes? `str = str.replace(/'/g, "'");`

Comment: That is indeed invalid JSON. The backslashes should be doubled in the string literal for them to make sense. Where do you get that string from?

Comment: In particular I got it from here: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/examples/v2.0/json/uber.json

Comment: Then I believe the literal you have provided is not the same as you get from that object. Be aware that the backslashes you provided in the JSON literal are resolved by the outer single quotes, which are not in the original construct. It would work with `'{ "name" : "This is some value \\"escaped\\""}'`, because then the first backslash is resolved by the single quoted string notation, leaving one backslash, which is the JSON escape character for the double quote. If you would `console.log` that last string, you'd only see one backslash each time. Is this the confusion?

Comment: See an illustration of what I mean: https://fiddle.jshell.net/u428x1k7/3/

Comment: Well I was trying to use .replace to try to get to what you are suggesting, but I can't even replace the \" with an x.  I'm trying to find a way to maybe manipulate it server side, but I think there has to be a way to "fix" the way its escaped.

Comment: @toxic53 you should do what @trincot said fix it server side by doing this: `\\"escaped\\"`...

Comment: @toxic53 the reason you can't replace `\"` is because the string actually only contains `"` not `\"`. `\"` is used to escape `"`.

Comment: @toxic, can you show the code where you start from the object that contains the property value which is a JSON string? The sample you gave just makes things more complicated because of the single quoted literal, which needs its proper escaping as well. Can you `console.log(obj.artifact);` and share what you get?

Comment: @toxic53 `"artifact": "{ \\"swagger\\"`...

Comment: Your escaping is useless `'"' === '\"'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to double escape the backslash when representing the JSON as a string. When you actually fetch that data from a service or API, you can just parse it and it should work fine. Check out the example below.

```js
var obj = {
  "name": "This is some value \"escaped\"",
  "artifact": "THE_JSON_STRING"
};

var test = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(test);

var str = '{"name":"This is some value \\"escaped\\"","artifact":"THE_JSON_STRING"}';
console.log(test);
console.log(test === str);

try {
  console.log(JSON.parse(str).name);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer but special thanks to @brso05 and trincot.  I really wanted to solve this client side but I ended up adding parsing logic server side to fix.  I was also only able to get it working if it had 3 backslashes.  For whats its worth here is the server side logic:  representation.setArtifact(service.getArtifact().replace("\\", "\\\\\\"));